# Получение ранней версии документа из истории

Tags: google-docs-api

Можно ли как-то получить предыдущую версию документа? И можно ли их сравнивать два документа из истории (получить diff) с помощью Google Docs API? И если такой API есть, то можно ли получить предыдущую версию таблицы (spreadsheet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Revisions) существует два способа получения ранних версий документа:

1. Получение всех версий с помощью запроса:

   ```
   GET /feeds/default/private/full/resource_id/revisions
   ```
2. Получение конкретной версии (`number`) с помощью запроса:

   ```
   GET /feeds/download/documents/Export?docId=doc_id&revision=number
   ```